# How to send an email to a mailchimp Automation on wordpress post publish

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp-api-v3.0

In wordpress, I'm trying to POST a specific email included as a value of a custom field (called customer_email) in each post to a mailchimp automation.

Below is the code I have and it's not working

```
function email_on_publish( $postid ) {

$api_key = API-KEY;
$workflow_id = WORKFLOW-ID;
$email_id = EMAIL-ID;
$email = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'customer_email', true );

$args = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'headers' => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'user:'. $api_key )
    ),
    'body' => json_encode(array(
            'email_address' => $email
    ))
);
$response = wp_remote_post( 'https://' . substr($api_key,strpos($api_key,'-')+1) . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/automations/' . $workflow_id . '/emails/' . $email_id . '/queue/' . md5(strtolower($email)), $args );

$body = json_decode( $response['body'] );

}
add_action( 'pending_to_publish', 'email_on_publish' );
add_action( 'draft_to_publish', 'email_on_publish' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: This has been resolved. There were two issues at hand.

1. I didn't need "md5(strtolower($email)" at the end of the post url.
2. Mailchimp requires you to send all prior emails in the workflow to the user before adding them to an automation. This was rendering all of my testing useless until I learned that.

Thanks for figuring this out, self!